# Check one box inside another box

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have tow boxes box1 and box2 i want to check whether box1 is inside the box2 using the cordinates can anyone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `Rectangle` object with your boxes coordinates like that:

```
var coords1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(box1.x, box1.y, box1.width, box1.height);
var coords2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(box2.x, box2.y, box2.width, box2.height);
```

Then simply use the [`containsRect:Boolean`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html#containsRect%28%29) method:

```
coord2.containsRect(coord1)
```

Answer (score 3):

use can use below code to check movieclip intercect or not

```
box1.getRect(this).intersects(box2.getRect(this))
```

this return true if intercect or false if fail

Answer (score 1):

Use the hittestobject method to detect collision

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly your boxes are, but if they are some sort of rectangles defined with top-left corner coordinates (x,y) and (width, height), then

```
if ((box1.x >= box2.x)&&(box1.y >= box2.y)&&(box1.width <= box2.width-(box1.x-box2.x)&&(box1.height <= box2.height-(box1.y-box2.y))) {
    // box1 is inside box2
}
```

should do the job.

If your boxes are 3D, then you will have to do the same with z and depth as well:

```
&&(box1.z >= box2.z)&&(box1.depth <= box2.depth-(box1.z-box2.z))
```

Comment: If you want to ensure that the box is inside the stage, then yes. Otherwise you just need to operate on width/height of the boxes.

Comment: ok can you please send me the code by comparing it with the stage

Comment: ok can you please send me the code by comparing it with the stage